# Открытие модального окна Fancybox при посещении сайта

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, обращаюсь за помощью! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить запуск модального окна, при входе на главную страницу сайта, при этом необходимо послать cookies для того, чтобы окно не было назойливым, т.е. если человек посетил страницу окно уже не показывать, срок жизни cookies - сутки. Я везде нахожу примеры  с запуском модального окно только по клику, мот плохо ищу...

*Костыль для cookies:*

```
//Отправим печеньку
    $(function(){
        var cookieValue = "true";       
        $.cookie("visit", cookieValue);        
        $.cookie("the_cookie", "the_value", {
            expires: 7,
            path: "/",
            secure: true
        });
    });
//Получаем печеньку
    $(function(){
        var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
        var getThe_value = $.cookie("the_value");
        alert("Пользовательская печенька: " + getCookieValue + " " + getThe_value);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JQuery для этого есть функция ready(). Она запускается после полной загрузки страницы.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {/* А здесь запускай функцию открытия модального окна*/ })
```

[Ссылка на доку](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Благодарствую! А, какие идеи на счет cookies? Я пример привел в вопросе.

Comment: @просто проверяете, если есть кука - то окно больше не открываем.

Comment: Ну а что с cookies? Делаешь проверку, если твоих cookies нет, то открываешь модальное окно и сетишь cookies, а если есть - то ничего не делаешь.

Comment: ну я так, удостоверится в правильности :) Всем спасибо!