# Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookieValue is not defined

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу снова вашей помощи, в продолжение [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/172705/jquery-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-fancybox-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) сделал [вот такой костыль](http://jsfiddle.net/eVta8/), странно, что модальное окошко с коннтентом не появляется, может вылезло из области видимости фрэйма, локально все работает. Вопрос вот в чем, как сделать так, чтобы мое окошко уже не появлялось если у пользователя имеется кука. Не могу сообразить как добавить *if(){}*

Вот так, не работает:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
        if (getCookieValue == true) {
            $("a.gallery2").fancybox(
                {                       
                    "padding" : 20, 
                    "imageScale" : false, 
                    "zoomOpacity" : false,  
                    "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000,   
                    "zoomSpeedOut" : 1000,  
                    "zoomSpeedChange" : 1000,
                    "frameWidth" : 700,
                    "frameHeight" : 600, 
                    "overlayShow" : true,
                    "overlayOpacity" : 0.8, 
                    "hideOnContentClick" :false,        
                    "centerOnScroll" : false                
            }).click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коллеги! Нашел решение:

Получается так, что сравнивать с переменной **getCookieValue** нельзя, поскольку переменная не является *глобальной*, а правильно сразу считывать *печеньку* в условии и сравнивать со значением условия.

Вот решение:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.gallery2").fancybox( {
        "padding" : 20, 
        "imageScale" : false,
        "zoomOpacity" : false,
        "zoomSpeedIn" : 1000,
        "zoomSpeedOut" : 1000,
        "zoomSpeedChange" : 1000,
        "frameWidth" : 700,
        "frameHeight" : 600,
        "overlayShow" : true,
        "overlayOpacity" : 0.8,
        "hideOnContentClick" :false,
        "centerOnScroll" : false
    });

if ($.cookie("visit") == "true") {
    $("a.gallery2").fancybox().click();
}

});
```

Да и вот еще одно решение:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Создаем cookie "visit"
  var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
  // Проверяем если cookie value = true
  if (getCookieValue == "true") {
      return false
  } else {
      $("a.gallery2").trigger("click");
  }
  $.cookie("visit:, "true", { expires: 1 }); // Устанавливаем время жизни cookie
  $("a.gallery2").fancybox({                       
     // Код fancybox
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Получаем печеньку с машины пользователя

```
$(function(){
    var getCookieValue = $.cookie("visit");
    alert("Пользовательская печенька: " + getCookieValue);
});
```

Если Вам нужно сделать, чтобы срабатывал `alert` только если `getCookieValue` не равен `true` то просто оберните его в `if`.
Как-то так:

```
if(getCookieValue != true) { alert("Пользовательская печенька: " + getCookieValue); }
```

Comment: alert это просто для проверки что печенька ушла! мне надо для того куска кода что отвечает за вывод модального окна

Comment: ну так оберните его в такой же if. Всё аналогично.

Comment: не работает!!! дополнил вопрос. Может я неправильно оборачиваю...?

Comment: Та вроде бы правильно. А что именно не работает? Как это "не работает". Это же как-то проявляется?

Comment: В названии вопроса указал ошибку ) Консоль firebug`а вывела сообщение: **Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookieValue is not defined**

Comment: @KryDos прокомментируй мой ответ пожалуйста!